# Intent problem with Map activity - how to fix that?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need to create an activity that must be pass next week. The activity is to make a home page with 2 button (Camera and Map) meaning I have to use intent function to work this App. But I have a problem, The camera button works fine but my maps is not working which is why Im here to ask for help.

I tried map =

```
(Button) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            { openMapsActivity();
            }
        });
```

then

p

```
ublic void openMapsActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

But doesnt seem to work

Here is the Code for my Main Activity:
package com.example.midexam;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int CAMERA_PICUTRE = 1;
    private static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE = "strKeyimage";


    ImageView imgPic;
    Button btnCamera, map;
    Bitmap photo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PICUTRE);

            }

        });
        map = (Button) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            { openMapsActivity();
            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PICUTRE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedUriImage = data.getData();
            try {
                photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),
                        selectedUriImage);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            imgPic.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable(IMAGE_RESOURCE, photo);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        photo = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(IMAGE_RESOURCE);
        imgPic.setImageBitmap(photo);


    }



    public void openMapsActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);

    }


}




Code for my MapActivity:

package com.example.midexam;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {


    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng central = new LatLng(8.404278, 124.290969);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(central)
                .title("Your Here")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.rsz_black)
                )
        );
        LatLng anthony = new LatLng(8.404407, 124.286771);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(anthony)
                .title("You arrive")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.rsz_black)
                )
        );
        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions() .add(
                central,
                new LatLng(8.404448, 124.290791),
                new LatLng(8.404575, 124.290651),
                new LatLng(8.404873, 124.287250),
                new LatLng(8.404358, 124.287154),
                anthony


                )
                        .width(10)
                        .color(Color.GREEN)
        );



        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            //TODO: Consider calling
            return;
        ;
        //add permission check
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (myLocation != null) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition2 = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()))
                    .zoom(17)
                    .bearing(90)
                    .tilt(40)
                    .build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition2));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public  void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

    }
}


my manifest: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.midexam">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

then my activity_map XML File;

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"

    />

and the Last activity_main.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.midexam.MainActivity"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPic"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgPic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgPic"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Camera"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnCamera"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCamera"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgPic"
        android:text="map"/>


</RelativeLayout>








I expected the Intent function I tried for the map activity will work out but I was wrong.
```

Comment: map not loaded or not navigate to map screen?

Comment: both. the result apk when clicking the button for the map. it will stop responding and close the apk.

Comment: have you register your activity on manifest?

Comment: I have 2 java class activity which is the mapsactivity for the map and Mainactivity where I input the code for the  camera. The mainactivity class is where I provide the intent code for the mapsactivity to call but this is where I get complicated. Was my intent code wrong? I provided all the codes to show you, who could help. The Mainactivity, mapsactivity, manifest, and xml layout file.

Comment: MapActivity is not registered in your manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your manifest application like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

Comment: Took me long to reply back. Thanks